# Redimensioning array to a different range of cells not picking up any value

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a list of names in 4 different columns and I want to filter the data associated with each name. But since the names are in different fields of the table, I need to change the 'Field' criteria and so had to run the code to filter four times. To do that I was trying to redimension my array after each run, but it is throwing up an error after it runs for the first time successfully.

When I checked in the immediate window, I found that it is not picking up any value in the array when I redim it for the second time. I have tried to use Erase to make sure the array does not have any previous values, but it is not working. Am I missing something here?

I get the error when the code tries to assign a name to the newly created sheet, but since it is blank it throws up the error 'name not found'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the code I am having.

```
ReDim arr(1 To lRow - 1)

For i = 1 To lRow - 1

    arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 33).Value

Next i

For j = 1 To lRow - 1

If fws.AutoFilterMode Then fws.AutoFilterMode = False

fws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=arr(j)

    Set FRange = fws.AutoFilter.Range
    Set nws = Worksheets.Add

    With nws
        .Name = arr(j)
    End With

    FRange.Copy
    nws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

Next j

fws.AutoFilterMode = False
lRow = fws.Range("AH" & fws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
i = 0

ReDim arr(1 To lRow - 1)

For i = 1 To lRow - 1

    arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 34).Value

Next i

j = 0

For j = 1 To lRow - 1

If fws.AutoFilterMode Then fws.AutoFilterMode = False

fws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=arr(j)

    Set FRange = fws.AutoFilter.Range
    Set nws = Worksheets.Add 

    With nws
        .Name = arr(j) `**I am getting error here**'
    End With

    FRange.Copy
    nws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

Next j
```

Comment: `arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 34).Value` which worksheet is active when this runs?  You need to explicitly link every Cells/Range reference to a worksheet object, or your code will not be robust.

Comment: I added the worksheet name before the cells, and this time it ran till the third instance of the filter loop but still getting the same error.

Comment: You only show the first two instances.  If your `arr(j)` value is empty (is it?) then you may still have a range reference problem.

Comment: you are absolutely right. When I rechecked it, I found that I did not add it to the last instance. It is working now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was kind of knowing that it was some silly mistake, but somehow not able to catch it after many iterations.

Comment: @TimWilliams how do I accept your answer so that you get the credit. I am not seeing any options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 34).Value
```

which worksheet is active when this runs? By default that will pick up the values from the ActiveSheet. You need to explicitly link every Cells/Range reference to a worksheet object, or your code will not be robust.